# Convert Signed Integer Date to Unix Seconds

Tags: php, c++, bit-manipulation

In PHP preferably, how do you convert -716980 to 12-21-04. I'm pretty sure that is the right date but I don't know how to come up with that date using a signed integer. Thank you. If you tell me in C++ that's ok too. I'm sure it has something to do with bitshift or bitwise operator.

Comment: Where are you seeing this negative number?

Comment: Two options: use math, or use search. Either way has already been solved if you actually put in some effort rather than just ask for the answer.

Comment: -716980 in unixtime is nowhere near 2004... It's 23 Dec 1969

Comment: @shrimpwagon, what makes you think the negative number is associated with that date? Please give us more info.

Comment: Hey, I know this looks totally crazy. Yes, it is a day count. This is from an old DOS system from late 80's. I'm totally sure about the outcome. Another example, -718355 is 03/17/2001. This I am sure of. I know that they used to use techniques like this to save on space. You would have to use either bitshifting or bit mask to get the right date. How? I don't know.

@jprofitt I'm not an idiot, thanks. I Googled for a solution thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

`-716980` is approximately equal to the number of days in 1962 years. As such I'd guess that the number you're dealing with is probably a day count; I can't figure out any way to make it come out to the year 2004, though.